# How to insulate brick/plaster walls from extreme heat?

Tags: insulation

I live in Rajkot, India. Temperature goes above 40 *C (104 *F) for at least 4 months a year.

I live in a single floor house with 3 sides of house and roof is exposed to sunlight.

It's a house built with brick walls, plaster and concrete slabs. flat roof floor is tiled with white ceramic tiles. Outer walls are painted white.

Is there anything I can do to reduce the inside temperature?

Comment: you are asking about insulating or reducing the temperature ?
Some things - plant trees around outer walls for shade. As for interior cooling you will need to Install fans inside the house or an air conditioner. Unless you plant those shade trees. Insulation might help you to a small degree but I think you will find it still gets very hot. If you were in a desert climate I would suggest a swamp cooler - but since you are not I will not make that suggestion.

Comment: I grew up in the heat of 1940s Odessa TX USA and the heat and humidity of New Orleans LA USA and 1950s Dallas TX USA. This was before refrigerated air and it was not pleasant in the summer. But I am sure it was easier than Rajkot Gujarat India. We had vegetation that helped and an 'attic fan' which pulled in outside air through the open windows, but 35 C air at 10 pm is still unpleasant. I feel for you. Solutions? Exterior shades maybe? Plants in low density soil in pots on the roof?

Answer (score 2):

Add a corrugated roof slanting from 1ft to 2ft high with the corrugations pointing to the higher side. Convection will pull the air to the higher side and out, providing some airflow. 
Insulate the ceilings of your living areas with rigid foam panels to limit heat gain from the roof. Provide awnings above your windows for shading in the summer, especially on the South facing windows, use a passive solar calculator online to size the awnings properly for passive sun heat in winter.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.